# Blur overlay over video

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a blurred overlay layer over a video.

I roughly recreated the effect in a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zswcctc7/1/

this is the situation more or less.

```
<div class="overlay-wrapper">
    <div class="video">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/vdCGnuccRv0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

So what i would like is instead of the white layer have a blurred layer, iOS style-ish. I tried a lot of things like blurjs, but nothing i find seems to work with video's.

Comment: can u make a scree with the effect that u want ?

Comment: It should just be any blur possible, doesn't matter which one. I just want a blur overlay over a video element.

Comment: just in the first picture or all video ?

Comment: all video, just the first picture would be very easy

Comment: the control video too ? (blak line play input etc...)

Comment: no, that's not necessary